# Can I on Xcode 4.6 have Interface Builder in separate app?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I know this is a stupid question, but I want to be sure. I want the old one. I have Mountain Lion.

Comment: Nope, it's all baked into one single app now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question as fully as possible: ***no***.

Moving on, the direction Apple has chosen to follow involves merging the previously distinct NIB editing aspects of things into the rest of the IDE, which makes quite a bit of sense - especially as you can directly create outlets, etc. by dragging from the relevant control to the header file when using the assistant view.

If it's any consolation, you'll get used to it pretty quickly.